# Validate users of Remote Active Directory in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group

I try to authenticate users belonging to remote ActiveDirectory  from my machine, which is not the same domain as the current machine or user domain. There will be no trust between my machine and remote ActiveDirectory machine.

**Initial Try**

I tried to authenticate a user(Input: sAMAccountName, machine's ipaddress, machine's domain username("Administrator") and machine's password(***). Able to get result that the user with 'sAMAccountName' do exist in ActiveDirectory.

**My Requirement**:

1. Imagine that already a user("qwerty") is created in ActiveDirectory
2. From my local machine, I will have the following information,

   a. Remote ActiveDirectory ipaddress

   b. Remote ActiveDirectory machine's username and password.

   c. Username and *password* of User "qwerty"
3. I need to check whether User "qwerty" is present in remote ActiveDirectory's users list and validate whether the *password* entered is same in ActiveDirectory's Users list

**Code I tried:**

```
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ipaddress/DC=dinesh,DC=com", name, password);
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        searcher.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + name + ")";

        try
        {
            SearchResult adsSearchResult = adsSearcher.FindOne();
            isValid = true;
            adsEntry.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            adsEntry.Close();
        }
```

Do I need to create a trust between local machine and remote ActiveDirectory machine before validating Users in a remote ActiveDirectory? If yes please tell how it can be done;

After creating trust, how can I validate Users?

===========================================================================

I am able to use the solution suggested by Rainer, but with a new problem. When I create a new user via C# code from a different machine, then some properties do not set properly.
[image: Properties not set when creating user]

Does this need to be set compulsorily while creating user?

Comment: When you write „remote active directory“, I assume it is not the same domain as the current machine or user domain. Correct ?  If there is no trust between both domains, you need to authenticate against the remote domain (what is your actual behavior). But what do you mean exactly with “authenticate users in remote AD”. Please explain this more detailed, what do you want to validate ? If the user really exists there ?

Comment: Hi Rainer, I have edited, answering your questions. Please take a look

Comment: Hi Dinesh, ok, now this becomes a bit clearer. I think I understand your requirements. Give me some time (1-2 days) for a answer and some suggestions (I read your question today and since I had to do with Active directory and LDAP some years ago, I will try to help you)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***First some basics (independent of this question)***

**Authentication**

The system checks if Bob is really Bob. In an Active Directory environment, this is usually done with a domain login from the workstation, Bob enters his username and password, and he gets a Kerberos ticket. Later, if he wants to access e.g. a file share on a remote fileserver, he does not need to login anymore, and can access the files without entering username/password.

**Authorization**

The system checks which resources Bob is allowed to access. Usually Bob is in domain groups, and a group is in the ACL (access control list) of the resource.

If there are multiple trusting domains, Bob needs to login in one domain, and can access resources in all other domains.
This is one of the main reasons using Active Directory: single sign on

**Checking if user / password is valid**

If you have a username and password and want to check if the password is valid, you have to do a login to the domain. There is no way of just “checking if the password is correct”.
Login means: if there is a security policy “lock account if more than 3 invalid logins”, the account will be locked out checking with wrong password, even if you “only want to check the user+password”.

**Using .NET Directory Service functions**

I assume here that the process is either run by a human account as a normal program, or the program is a Windows service or a scheduled task which runs under a domain “technical user” account. In this case, you do not need to provide credentials for using the AD functions. If accessing other trusting AD domains, this is also true.
If you want to login to a “foreign domain”, and there is no trust, you need to provide a username+password (as in your code).

**"Manually" authenticating a user**

Normally, this should not be needed. Example: ASP.NET intranet usage. The user access a web application on the current domain or trusting domain, the authentication is done “in the background” by browser and IIS (if integrated Windows authentication is on). So you never need to handle user passwords in the application.

I don’t see many use cases where a password is handled by code.

One may that your program is a helper tool for storing emergency user accounts/passwords. And you want to check periodically if these accounts are valid.

This is a simple way to check:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
...

PrincipalContext principalContext = 
     new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "192.168.1.1");

bool userValid = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(name, password);
```

One can also use the older, raw ADSI functions:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
....

bool userOk = false;
string realName = string.Empty;

using (DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = 
   new DirectoryEntry"LDAP://192.168.1.1/DC=ad,DC=local", name, password))
{
    using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry))
    {
        searcher.Filter = "(samaccountname=" + name + ")";
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");

        SearchResult adsSearchResult = searcher.FindOne();

        if (adsSearchResult != null)
        {
            if (adsSearchResult.Properties["displayname"].Count == 1)
            {   
                realName = (string)adsSearchResult.Properties["displayname"][0];
            }
            userOk = true;
        }
    }
}
```

If your real requirement is actually a validity check of user+password, you can do it in one of these ways.

However, if it is a "normal application", which just wants to check if the entered credentials are valid, you should rethink your logic. In this case, you better should rely on the single sign on capabilities of AD.

If there are further questions, please comment.

> > b. Remote ActiveDirectory machine's username and password.

This sounds a bit unclear. I assume you mean "a username and corresponding password in the remote domain".

There is also the concept of a machine account, which is the hostname appended with $. But that's another topic.

---

Creating new user

Option 1

```
using (DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://192.168.1.1/CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=local", 
        name, password))
{
    using (DirectoryEntry newUser = directoryEntry.Children.Add("CN=CharlesBarker", "user"))
    {
        newUser.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = "CharlesBarker";
        newUser.Properties["givenName"].Value = "Charles";
        newUser.Properties["sn"].Value = "Barker";
        newUser.Properties["displayName"].Value = "CharlesBarker";
        newUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = "CharlesBarker";
        newUser.CommitChanges();
    }
}
```

Option 2

```
using (PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "192.168.1.1", 
    "CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=local", name, password))
{
    using (UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext))
    {
        userPrincipal.Name = "CharlesBarker";
        userPrincipal.SamAccountName = "CharlesBarker";
        userPrincipal.GivenName = "Charles";
        userPrincipal.Surname = "Barker";
        userPrincipal.DisplayName = "CharlesBarker";
        userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName = "CharlesBarker";
        userPrincipal.Save();
    }
}
```

I leave as an exercise to you to find out which attribute goes into which User dialog entry field :-)

Comment: Thanks Rainer, the only thing is I am able to validate only those users who are created in Active Directory directly. If I create a new user via C# code from remote local machine, Property 'User logon name (pre_Windows 2000' is set to some random string. So I am unable to validate users created via c# code. ( I have attached the screenshot in question and edited the same)

Comment: You are right. You have to set some fields explicitly. See my edited answer.